# Does DocuSign Connect work with basic HTTP auth details?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign connect to update the state of my app after an event happens on a document.

I have set up my account like so:

[image]

At the moment my "URL to Publish" looks something similar to `https://key:secret@example.herokuapp.com`. However when I look in the logs I always seem to receive something similar to:

`error: Exception in EnvelopeIntegration.RunIntegration: key :: https://key:secret@example.herokuapp.com/webhook :: Error - The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized`

When I copy the Envelope Data into a file locally (complete-webhook.xml) and I run the following command through the command line it seems to run successfully:

`curl -i -X POST -d @complete-webhook.xml https://key:secret@example.herokuapp.com/webhook`

Has anybody got any ideas as to the reason why this could be happening?

Comment: Hmm can't see anything obvious so far.  The one thing I see in the DocuSign Connect guide under the `Require Acknowledgement` option is it writes:  "Select this option to log posting failures. Because DocuSign
Connect is the client in this case, you must also add the DocuSign public *signed by* certificate to your server's certificate store."  Is it perhaps a certificate issue, have you tried testing without that set?

Answer (score 1):

When you use a url such as `https://username:password@example.com/`, your client takes the `username:password` part of the url and uses it to create an `Authorization: Basic` header.

You can try it yourself, create a [requestb.in](http://requestb.in/) and then use the curl command

```
curl -X POST -d "fizz=buzz" http://username:password@requestb.in/12345
# where 12345 is your requestb.in address
```

The result on requestb.in:

1. A request to just `/12345` (the incoming url does not include the username or password)
2. The request includes the header `Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=`

If you put `dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=` through a base64 decoder, you get `username:password`

**Answer**, at this point, the Connect system does not support sending basic authentication information when it calls listeners. I have filed an internal feature request.

**Work-around**

Your listener url can include a query parameter that serves as a password. eg. `example.com/webhook/?pw=9e47a953-c105-44c5-ba5c-4bb77d63694d

Then, in your listener, simply reject any request that does not include the `pw` query parameter and the value that you chose.

In its requests to your listener, the Connect system will use any query parameters that you originally set when you added the Connect subscription.

Comment: Hi @Larry K - Has this internal feature request been actioned yet? I can see it has specifically for the "Connect" app, but I am looking for EventNotification webhook authorisation. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @MitchKent  As you've noticed, Connect at the account level now supports Basic Authentication. Unfortunately the feature has not yet been added to the eventNotification object. It is on the roadmap, but no date yet. Please ask your DocuSign contact to add your customer details to DocuSign enhancement request CONNECT-1084

Comment: Hi Larry. Many thanks for your time and response, I'll do just that.

Comment: Anyone get it resolved please let me know as I am facing same issue. Thanks

Comment: I was just on my DocuSign Sandbox account and I was able to turn on Basic Authentication for my Connect notifications.  It gives you a place to enter the username and password you want to use.  I HAVE NOT had a chance to test this yet.